# Apache Solr 6.5 Multi-valued field query

Tags: apache, solr, multivalue

I have a Solr 6.5 index with schema:
OrderId, OrderType, AirNumber & more..

My document looks like:

```
"OrderId":"-7878676767676",
"OrderType:"["Fee",
             "Insurance",
             "Air",
             "Fee"]
"AirNumber":["",
             "",
             "[2608620989121, 2608620989123]",
             ""],
```

When I query for AirNumber, I am not able to retrieve the above order.

```
q=AirNumber:2608620989121
```

My schema for AirNumber is:

```
<field name="AirNumber" type="token" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false"/>
```

I have tried different combinations to query & I have tried with AirNumber as "string" too, Nothing works. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For string field type it won't work because this field type doesn't tokenize the values, so you would need to query for the exact value "[2608620989121, 2608620989123]".

And for the "token" type, it depends on your configuration of the fieldtype "token".

A way to make it work in your use case is to configure the token field type something like this:

```
<fieldType name="token" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This will make it tokenizes your multivalued input so you'll be able to find each number separately.

Comment: Did you reindex the content with this configs? You can check in the Analaysis tab in solr web UI how it's indexing and searching against this field

Comment: I've tested this in Solr 6.2.1 and 6.6.1 and it worked in both.

Comment: I inserted a new document and I tested against it. I reloaded the core for reindex, still doesnt work.

Comment: This is not a TextField, I have numbers in that field. Would that make a difference?

Comment: No.. I've tested with your data ant it worked. Can you share your full schema.xml and solrconfig.xml?

Comment: One thing that I noticed is that the Analyze tab in Admin UI doesnt have my updated schema info, the AirNumber field is still a string.

Comment: That's the problem :). You're probably editing the wrong schema or not reloading core after editing. You can try to reload or create a new core just for test.